# CiviCase Error.. Help!

Tags: custom-fields, civicase, error, php

I am getting an error when I click *manage case*. Looks like it has something to do with custom fields for a custom field type (DLSE Claim).

Wordpress 4.4.2
CiviCRM 4.6.11

This happened after upgrading to 4.7.. after rolling back, it worked for a while, then started acting funky again.

Below is the debug.  Thanks!

backTrace

```
#0 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(182): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(976): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: no such field", -19, 16, (Array:2), "\n      SELECT civicrm_value_dlse_claim_1.id as civicrm_value_dlse_claim_1_id...")
#4 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(564): DB_Error->DB_Error(-19, 16, (Array:2), "\n      SELECT civicrm_value_dlse_claim_1.id as civicrm_value_dlse_claim_1_id...")
#5 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -19, NULL, NULL, "\n      SELECT civicrm_value_dlse_claim_1.id as civicrm_value_dlse_claim_1_id...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(895): DB_common->raiseError(-19, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1054 ** Unknown column 'civicrm_value_dlse_claim_details_4.unpaid_wages_162' ...")
#7 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(328): DB_mysql->mysqlRaiseError()
#8 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysql->simpleQuery("\n      SELECT civicrm_value_dlse_claim_1.id as civicrm_value_dlse_claim_1_id...")
#9 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2442): DB_common->query("\n      SELECT civicrm_value_dlse_claim_1.id as civicrm_value_dlse_claim_1_id...")
#10 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1634): DB_DataObject->_query("\n      SELECT civicrm_value_dlse_claim_1.id as civicrm_value_dlse_claim_1_id...")
#11 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(325): DB_DataObject->query("\n      SELECT civicrm_value_dlse_claim_1.id as civicrm_value_dlse_claim_1_id...")
#12 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1192): CRM_Core_DAO->query("\n      SELECT civicrm_value_dlse_claim_1.id as civicrm_value_dlse_claim_1_id...", TRUE)
#13 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/CustomGroup.php(735): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("\n      SELECT civicrm_value_dlse_claim_1.id as civicrm_value_dlse_claim_1_id...")
#14 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/CustomGroup.php(692): CRM_Core_BAO_CustomGroup::buildTreeEntityDataFromQuery((Array:4), "\n      SELECT civicrm_value_dlse_claim_1.id as civicrm_value_dlse_claim_1_id...", (Array:3))
#15 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/CustomGroup.php(626): CRM_Core_BAO_CustomGroup::buildEntityTreeSingleFields((Array:4), 60, (Array:52), (Array:3))
#16 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Case/Form/CaseView.php(190): CRM_Core_BAO_CustomGroup::getTree("Case", Object(CRM_Case_Form_CaseView), "60", NULL, "3")
#17 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(455): CRM_Case_Form_CaseView->preProcess()
#18 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(94): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#19 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Case_Form_CaseView), "display")
#20 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Case_Form_CaseView), "display")
#21 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(353): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#22 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Case/Page/Tab.php(115): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#23 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Case/Page/Tab.php(204): CRM_Case_Page_Tab->view()
#24 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Case_Page_Tab->run((Array:4), NULL)
#25 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#26 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#27 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1189): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#28 [internal function](): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#29 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-includes/plugin.php(525): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:1))
#30 /home/laaneorg/public_html/portwp/wp-admin/admin.php(236): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#31 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

duh! I just had to Disable the custom field.  Works fine now.

value_dlse_claim_details_4.unpaid_wages_162